# Como ver los paquetes que se están instalando?

Tags: npm

Hay alguna opción o paquete que me muestre un contador de paquetes instalados mientras se ejecuta

```js
npm install
```

Algo así como lo hace pnpm:

[image: Consola de pnpm]

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el argumento `--loglevel verbose` al comando que deseas ejecutar y todos los registros se guardarán en un `npm-debug.log` en el directorio de trabajo actual.

Ejemplo de uso: `npm install ionic --loglevel verbose`

también puedes hacerlo de manera permanente solo edita la configuración global de `npm` solo corre el comando `npm config edit` & agrega `loglevel=verbose`

Para hacer el update vía terminal usa `npm config set loglevel verbose`